# Get one column in CakePHP 3.x controller

Tags: arrays, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to get one colum with sql and convert it in array and use in controller?

```
$allid = $this ->TabelName
            ->find('list',array(
                'fields' => array('id'),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User_id' => '1'
                )
            ));
        $this->set(compact('allid'));



        $data = $allid->toArray();
        echo $data;
```

What i need is to have in controller this **$data=array("1","2","3");** and this are all ids from TableName. Can someone tell me how can i do this?

Comment: can you please tell the exact cakephp version? You wrote cake3 in the title but then you tagged both cake2 and cake3 and the syntax seems cake2

Comment: @arilia 3.x is the version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cake 3 you can use Collections

```
$allid = $this ->TableName->find()
    ->select(['id'])
    ->where(['User_id' => '1']);

$allid = $allid
    ->extract('id')
    ->toArray();
```

see the manual [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::extract)

instead of extract - if you need to obtain a string representing the array - you can use map and reduce()

```
$allid = $allid
   ->map(function ($value, $key) {
        return '"'.$value->id.'"';
    })
    ->reduce(function ($accumulated, $value) {
        return $accumulated.", " .$value;
    });
```

Comment: i need this conversion in controlle so that i can use it there and i can't find a solution for that. I know that i can do it in view by iteration (foreach...) but i need it in controller

Comment: you get an error because you are trying to echo an array. Use `print_r($allid)` or `debug($allid)` instead of `echo` and you'll see the array

Comment: how can i order that like this **array("1","2","3")**? because it show me like (int) [0 => (int) 1,(int) 1 => (int) 2,(int) 2 => (int) 3]?

Comment: That's just the way debug show the data. You asked for an array and you have an array that you can use where you want. But if for some reason you want that precise string you have to manipulate the array. But you question is not clear at all